# Web Reference Access Violation in Delphi 2005 .NET

Tags: web-services, delphi, .net-1.1, delphi-2005

I am creating an application that consumes a web-service in Delphi-2005 .NET.

How I am doing it is adding a web-reference to the project and then supplying the url to the wsdl. This seems to work fine in that a pas file is generated and added to the project but as soon as I compile the project I get and access violation in the Ide in dcc90il.dll

Anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been unable to get this to work or even determine why it is failing. I ended up generating code from the wsdl using wsdl.exe from MS and then compiled the source to an assembly using csc.exe.

The assembly works fine but Delphi generates obscure errors if an error is returned from the server.

imo Delphi sucks.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect a fundamental .net interop, IDE, or RTL bug in Delphi2005.net. Can you download the trial version of Delphi2007.net and try it there?

Comment: for various reasons Delphi2007 is not an option, so even if it did work there it would not help.